# Doctrine Query builder get field of foreign entity

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query like :

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
    $qb->select('m.id', 'IDENTITY(m.home)');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

`m.home` field is a foreign key to another table (This other table has a field ID and another name).

With this I get Id of `m` and id of the foreign key.

How can I get the name field of my other instead of id ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the data of the associated entity with a join:

```
SELECT m.id, home.name
FROM YourEntity AS m
JOIN m.home AS home
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `leftJoin` to get data from a relationship:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');
$qb = $qb->leftJoin('AppBundle\Entity\Home', 'h');
$qb->select('m.id', 'IDENTITY(m.home)', 'h.name');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Replace 'AppBundle\Entity\Home' by the namespaced class of your entity "home".